# About how to pass the ParseObject(Object) using Rest API(service) in Installation class in android?

Tags: android, rest, parse-platform, xamarin, push-notification

I am sagar, i am trying to implement the `Parse Push-Notification in` android using `REST API (Service)`, and i am almost got success in implement the `Push-Notification` in  `Xamarin-Android` using `REST API`. But i got stuck with one part in sending the Data into `REST service`. I trying to pass the `ParseObject` in service, but the in parse table there is a need of Object,(). I have tried to pass the `ParseObject as` below:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParseUser.CurrentUser)
```

It convert `ParseObject into` array and array is not accepted in table and ,i got failed to save it in table. because there i a need of object.
I need solution or suggestion from developer guys. Yours help will be appreciated. I am trying the below code to achieve the result.

```
 public static void RegisterPush(string regristrationId)
 {   
    if (regristrationId != null) {
        string appID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string restID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string masterID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        try {
            var client = new RestClient ("https://api.parse.com");

            var request = new RestRequest ("1/installations", RestSharp.Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader ("X-Parse-Application-Id", appID);
            request.AddHeader ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", restID);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (appID, masterID);
            request.Parameters.Clear ();
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("ParseUser.CurrentUser-->"+ (ParseObject) ParseUser.CurrentUser);

            //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParseUser.CurrentUser)
            string strJSONContent = "{\"user\" :"+ JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParseUser.CurrentUser)+",\"owner\":\"" +         ParseUser.CurrentUser.ObjectId + "\",\"deviceType\":\"android\",\"GCMSenderId\":\"1234567890\",\"appName\":\"abcdefgh\",\"pushType\":\"gcm\",\"deviceToken\":\"" + regristrationId + "\"}";

            Console.Error.WriteLine("json string-->"+ strJSONContent);

            request.AddParameter ("application/json", strJSONContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                Console.Error.WriteLine ("response for android parse installation-->" + response.Content);
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        }
    }
}`

Output:{"user" :[{"Key":"dealOffered","Value":4},{"Key":"dealRequested","Value":5},{"Key":"displayName","Value":"Cook"},{"Key":"email","Value":"lorenzo@gmail.com"},{"Key":"firstName","Value":"Lorenzo"},{"Key":"lastName","Value":"Cook"},{"Key":"mobileNumber","Value":9999999999.0},{"Key":"picture","Value":{"IsDirty":false,"Name":"tfss-afd25c29-6679-4843-842c-fe01f7fcf976-profile.jpg","MimeType":"image/jpeg","Url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/profile.jpg"}},{"Key":"provider","Value":"password"},{"Key":"userType","Value":"Merchant"},{"Key":"username","Value":"merchant@sailfish.com"},{"Key":"zipCode","Value":2342343}],"owner":"3cF1vHUXkW","deviceType":"android","GCMSenderId":"1234567890123","appName":"Sailfish","pushType":"gcm","deviceToken":"APA91bE3bsTIInQcoloOBE4kdLVVHVTRVtNyA1A788hYSC15wAVu8mUg-lwk7ZPk370rngrK7J6OoLmiM9HRr1CGPaBo6LCNrSUL7erBku4vepaFFkQzgqS6BcAemp"}

Error:{"code":111,"error":"invalid type for key user, expected  *_User, but got array"}
```

Comment: Think it would be much easier using cloud code

Answer (score 1):

maven

I found the solution in , parse xamarin docs, in one query , the way is simple, but i little bit hard to found out.

The issue is with the data passing in json format in REST, to pass any pointer using REST API, use as below.

The  solution is as below:
`{

```
"user":{
    "__type":"Pointer",
    "className":"_User",
    "objectId":"qYvzFzGAzc"
},
"owner":"qYvzFzGAzc",
"deviceType":"android",
"GCMSenderId":"123456789",
"appName":"NiceApp",
"pushType":"gcm",
"deviceToken":"APA91bFeM10jdrCS6fHqGGSkON17UjEJEfvJEmGpRM-d6hq3hQgDxKHbyrqAIxMnEGgbLEZf0E9AllHxiQQQCdEFiNMF1_A8q0n9tGpBE5NKhvS2ZGJ9PZ7585puWqz_1Z1EjSjOvgZ1LQo708DeL2KzA7EFJmdPAA"
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your column `user` is set up wrong. It should show as a Pointer<_User> not Pointer

If you load this class in your Data Browser, is the "user" key defined as a string, or a Pointer <_User>

This error seems to indicate that this is a string column, which is why the Parse.User object is not being accepted as a valid value. You might have tried setting a string on this key before, which in turn type-locked the "user" key as a string column.

Found it on the examples given on this page - https://www.parse.com/docs/rest

Comment: Thanx for your Quick response,but Pls can  show you me an example of it. 
where i am going wrong.

Comment: You are giving key `user` and parsing the complete Json Object, *thats why you are getting that exception*.

Comment: what should i use it instead of key 'user'..?
`<_User>` or `Pointer<_User>`

Comment: can you please show me the `JSON string`  the proper format while calling the `Rest..?`

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your REST API connection while passing ParseObject?
Because your error says:

```
   Error:{"code":111,"error":"invalid type for key user, expected  *_User, but got array"}
```

Here `"code":111`This error code comes when server refuse for connection

Comment: this error is about passing about how to pass the parseObject in `REST API` in xamarin android.
If i change the key it shows different error.